# how to enable javascript of remote web page in electron app popup browserwindow

Tags: javascript, security, electron

I have an electron (4.0) app. I'm using the openid/appauth-js node module.
This module brings up a native browser window when performing openid connect hybrid flows.
(I am using IdentityServer 3 for the server)
I want to use an electron BrowserWindow instead.

The flow works up to the point where the consent screen is shown.
The consent screen has a minified version of jQuery (v1.11.0) followed by Bootstrap (v3.0.3).

The page displays fine in native browser, but in electron I get the message "Bootstrap requires jQuery"

I've tried set the browserwindow option nodeIntegration:true (I appreciate this is overkill). I've partially looked at pre-load aswell, but I think this is undesirable as the web service could be used by other clients.
I've also tried --enable-sandbox together with sandbox: true, but this breaks the main window.

I've also tried debugging the javascript code to identify why it fails to run correctly, but its complicated due to the openid flow interaction.

I require the popup window to execute remote resource javascript like a chrome or other mainstream browser.
Instead Bootstrap fails to recognise jQuery is already loaded

Comment: This issue looks highly relevant, so I'll consider it next...
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/254